# Can I create a stored procedure in mysql using a txt file?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My server OS is Red Hat 6 with MySQL. I'm using this line in a `.sh` file to run some jobs on the server:

```
mysql -u root -p[password] databasename < MySQL_JOBS_SENTENCES.txt
```

The content of the `.txt` file is:

```
call procedure1(date(now()));
call procedure2(date(now()));
call procedure3(current_Date());
```

Can I create or load a new stored procedure from a `.txt` file into my database the same way?

Answer (score 2):

If you can execute SQL and you have sufficient privileges to create a stored procedure then you can create the stored procedure.

I'm assuming you can execute SQL with the `.sh` file above since you are currently using it to run jobs.  Since it looks like you are using this to perform maintenance on a scheduled basis I am going to further assume that you want to update the database/deploy changes using the same mechanism.  If this is true I would caution against this plan.  While it might seem nice to automate a deployment at midnight while you're sleeping [if anything goes wrong](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/02/consulting-lines-happens-if-that-doesnt-work/), you won't enjoy the fallout when your boss/customer/angry person X wakes you up because the world is on fire....